# Hibernate column transformer

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. I have a use case where I need to apply a transformer (encrypt/encode) on the persistent class member just before it is saved and (decrypt/decode) after the data is loaded. What I am looking at is something like this:

```
public class PersistentClass {

    @Encrypt(transformer=DoubleTransformer)
    public Double dataToBeEncoded;

    public Double persistAsIs;
}
```

All my transformers result in text data that will be persisted in db and I want to define transformers once and reuse it in all the persistent classes. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is: [JPA life cycle callbacks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg014.htm), or [Hibernate inerceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html). Just implement the Pre-Persist, Pre-Update and Post-Load listeners.